# Automatically Refresh Comments with Ajax

Tags: feature-request, comments

A lot of cool ajaxy effects are implemented all over SO, for example if I score some points, my score reflects these points immediately. Could we apply the same methodology to comments associated to OPs on the results page?

For example, if I click into a post and add a comment to the OP, then go back to results page, the post I just clicked into will have a comment count of 1. Then I do some actual work for 10 minutes then come back to SO, and without having to refresh, the post I clicked into previously now has a comment count of 6, which would encourage me to click into the post. However if the count is still 1, I move on.

The comment counts displayed on the results page would only apply to the OP.

Comment: Where are you seeing comment counts? Are you thinking of *answers*?

Comment: You don't, hence the feature request. No not answers, the OP. How many comments does the OP currently have.

Comment: so this would save you 1 click?  How would this benefit the thousands of other users?

Comment: Comments are meant for clarification of the question details, not for general discussion. There's no benefit to adding support for count display for the transitory, second-class content of comments IMO.

Comment: Ya I disagree. Views are also transitory, and offer no real benefit either. Sure you can glean popularity from the view count, but the same could be said for a comment count.

Comment: But what is the benefit for everyone?  You've only explained how this would benefit you.  As a random user, at least the view count can give me an idea on the relative popularity of a question.  The comment count does not reflect the popularity or quality... in fact there are plenty of bad questions that have high comment counts.

Comment: The point about views vs comment count was responded too in my previous comment. I find it hard to believe that I would be the only one benefiting from this suggestion. The comment count would be good for those of us who may be tracking a specific question from the results page (i.e. the link is now gray as it has been previously clicked).

Comment: @MikePurcell but my point was it only benefits a specific person who has commented previously and wants to monitor the question.  For every 1 commenter there are dozens of other viewers who won't give a damn about the comment count.  The comment count does not provide useful information to the general public, only to specific users.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Someone with no vested interest, but having knowledge related to a specific post, sees the post with 237 views, 0 answers, and 0 comments. Chances are the user would at least peruse the question to offer some guidance in the form of a quick comment. And conversely, if the comment count is 17, chances are they would not click at all, as others have started helping the OP.

Comment: @MikePurcell I personally disagree, I can't see how the comment count would encourage me or deter me from viewing the question since the comments could be helpful or could just be people offering unhelpful advice or the OP repeatedly asking why people are downvoting or aren't answering or commenting.  But I would encourage you to editing your reasoning into your question because without it, the feature request sounds very selfish (i.e. "I want this feature because it would benefit me")

Comment: You are countering my seemingly selfish reasoning with your own. The example is only there to demonstrate a use case for the suggestion.

Comment: @MikePurcell your choice, I only suggested it because your feature request doesn't really explain much benefit in my opinion.  But I'm just 1 opinion.

Comment: Despite your arguments to the contrary, I see no benefit to the majority of users from implementing this suggestion.

Comment: Dunno why everyone says this would be useless. On the main site, the presence of a large number of comments is a good metric signaling questions to avoid because they contain insufficient information to answer them.

Comment: *"The comment count would be good for those of us who may be tracking a specific question from the results page"*. I would open this question in a new tab and leave it there (or "favorite" it for a while and close the tab) while I browse for other questions. On a more serious note, please at least list some benefits that this feature can give. So far, I only found 2. (the one you wrote on comment, and Cody's comment). Edit: won't you be notified already if there is a response after you add comment to OP?

Comment: Don't we get prompted to take comments to chat if we're conversing back and forth with someone on a question or answer?  Doesn't that give some indication of the lack of worth of a high comment count on a question?  If you're just taking comment count as the metric, there's no indication that there are only two people involved in 20 comments.

Comment: See? If I saw the score and the comment count at 16, I would know I am getting flammed, and not have to click into the post.

Answer (score 6):

The tag wiki itself says ["Comments are second-class citizens"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments). But the content, not count, should be more important anyway (you can go to the question page for that).